# No ringtone from text

Tags: iphone, ios

when I receive a text from my husband's phone, there is no ringtone. The message shows up on the screen, but there is no alert tone. Other texts are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

1. Contacts
2. Locate the person you're talking about
3. Click Edit right on top
4. Remove the custom ringtone which has been set
5. Save it and return to springboard
6. Everything should be back to normal